# Regex greedy issue

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm sure this one is easy but I've tried a ton of variations and still cant match what I need.  The thing is being too greedy and I cant get it to stop being greedy.

Given the text:

```
test=this=that=more text follows
```

I want to just select:

```
test=
```

I've tried the following regex

```
(\S+)=(\S.*)
(\S+)?=
[^=]{1}
...
```

Thanks all.

Comment: you say you want to just select "text=" but that doesn't occur anywhere in your sample text!

Comment: wooops.. you're right.. it should have been test=.. I'll edit it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here:

```
// matches "test=, test"
(\S+?)=

or

// matches "test=, test" too
(\S[^=]+)=
```

you should consider using the second version over the first. given your string `"test=this=that=more text follows"`, version 1 will match `test=this=that=` then continue parsing to the end of the string. it will then backtrack, and find `test=this=`, continue to backtrack, and find `test=`, continue to backtrack, and settle on `test=` as it's final answer.

version 2 will match `test=` then stop. you can see the efficiency gains in larger searches like multi-line or whole document matches.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something like

^(\S+?=)

The caret ^ anchors the regex to the beginning of the string. The ? after the + makes the + non-greedy.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [lazy quantifiers](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance) *?, +?, ??, and {n, n}?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this:

```
(\S+?)=(\S.*)
```

Comment: I coulda swore I tried all these variants.  I switched to a gui regex editor for testing and it does not seem to "work right".  I added the ? into my code and all is well.  Thanks all!

Comment: This will actually get "text" in the first group and "this=that=more text follows" in the second.  Owen's would get "text=" and "text" in the two groups.  I assumed that he wanted the = stripped out based on his previous tries.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy quantifiers work, but they also can be a performance hit because of backtracking.

Consider that what you really want is "a bunch of non-equals, an equals, and a bunch more non-equals."

```
([^=]+)=([^=]+)
```

Your examples of `[^=]{1}` only matches a single non-equals character.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only "text=", I think that a simply:

```
^(\w+=)
```

should be fine if you are shure about that the string "text=" will always start the line.

the real problem is when the string is like this:

> this=that= more test= text follows

if you use the regex above the result is "this=" and if you modify the above with the reapeater qualifiers at the end, like this:

```
^(\w+=)*
```

you find a tremendous "this=that=", so I could only imagine the trivial:

```
[th\w+=]*test=
```

Bye.